# How to remove this annoying text from powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I find a powerpoint on a telegram channel and I want to edit and work on that powerpoint. but there is a text on the above left of the powerpoint I try to delete this but I can't:

[image]

I also tried this way:

[image]

And clicked on the Section Header. but the glowing line below the arrows disappeared. So how can I fix it?

Comment: Its by default in layout I think. Have you tried to hide by adding a box or draw on it.

Comment: @HarshaMadusanka: Hmm good Idea. I tried it now, I draw a black rectangle on it but the color of the rectangle is not the same as theme of the slide

Answer (score 1):

Choose View | Slide Master

In Slide Master view, look at the topmost thumbnail. See if you can select and delete the text there. With luck, that'll be all it takes.

Otherwise, click on each of the layouts that are indented below the topmost one and see if you can click/select/delete the unwanted text on each of the layout slides.

If that doesn't help, it's also possible that the text is from a background picture applied to the main master/all of the layouts. Go back to the main master, rightclick the slide, choose Format Background and if it's set to an image, change it to solid color and choose black.